# AB-Matter paper, understanding what a variable represents?

Tags: physics

One meter of AB-needle has line having n = 5.7*10^-14 nucleons with mass m = 1.67*10^-27 kg. Total mass of one meter AB-needle equals only 10^-12 kg/m.

M1 = nm = 5.7*10^-14 ×1.67*10^-27 = 10^-12 kg/m.

One million kilometers of AB-needle weights only 10^-3 kg/Mm. For transferring the large force we can take the thin cable from AB-needles.

What does n stands for I'm really confused, how can you have a number lower than 1 to count the number of nucleons in a meter string of AB-matter. I thought you would count the number in a meter needle and times it by mass of each nucleons to arrive at mass of a length of needle?

http://www.gsjournal.net/Science-Journals/Research%20Papers-Quantum%20Theory%20/%20Particle%20Physics/Download/5244 page 10

[what does n mean?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugdgW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely to be a typo (on both lines). It most likely meant $n=5.7(10^{14})$.

We see on the next line of calculation that this interpretation would make sense, given the result.

$$5.7(10^{14}) ×1.67(10^{-27}) = 10^{-12}$$

Comment: (5.7*10^14)*(1.67*10^-27)= 9.519e-13

Comment: @BlingSco $9.519(10^{-13})\approx 10^{-12}$

Comment: Seems like quite an approximation, is that allowed in mathematics, cause significant figure rules, decimal point rules etc. or is the author demonstrating a point, you think?

Comment: @BlingSco From context, this seems to be a physics journal. Approximations are common especially since these numbers are empirically measured. They don't make a huge difference, and the order of magnitude is often more important. Here, rounding up to the nearest order of magnitude seems a sensible thing to do.